# Is it possible to use the value of a variable to define the name of another variable in a JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment, session-cookies

I'm trying to use the value of a variable as the name of another variable inside of a string.

I've searched, and seen similar questions asked, and the answer seems to be "learn how to use arrays, dummy." But I have a somewhat unique version of the question, I think.

I'm not even good enough at Javascript to explain the issue, so it'd probably be easier to just show the code, I surrounded the parts I'm confused about in double stars (**):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function bake(cookietype,ingredient) {
    **ingredient**=document.recipes.**ingredient**.value;
    document.cookie=**cookietype** + "=" + **ingredient**;
}
</script>

<form name="recipes">
    Name: <input type="text" name="flour" size="20" onBlur="bake('oreo','flour')">
    Email: <input type="text" name="eggs" size="20" onBlur="bake('milano','eggs')">
</form>
```

So if this makes any sense, I'd like to set a cookie named after the first variable passed to the function 'bake', and I'd like the contents of the cookie to be the value of the corresponding form input element. Is this possible? It has to be, right? I'm just not nearly educated enough to do what seems fairly simple.

Comment: God, I love this website. An instant connection to thousands of people way smarter than me who actively enjoy helping out dummies like myself. Stackoverflow rules

Comment: Isn't it great? Until you get those people who take this way too seriously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you're going about it the right way, is all - no need to create a variable and have it be named as the specific form element. Instead of passing `'flour'` as the second parameter, pass `this`...so it would be `onBlur="bake('oreo',this)"`. Then, in your function, you can use `ingredient.value` to get the form input's value. Here's what I'd use as the function:

```
function bake(cookietype,ingredient) {
    var textbox_value=ingredient.value;
    document.cookie=cookietype + "=" + textbox_value;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<form name="recipes">
    Name: <input type="text" name="flour" size="20" onBlur="bake('oreo',this)">
    Email: <input type="text" name="eggs" size="20" onBlur="bake('milano',this)">
</form>
```

`this` refers to the HTML element this is being called from. So when you pass it to the function, you can reference it by the parameter named `ingredient`. It just seems a lot cleaner than using text to specify the name of the element in the form...especially since in your example, the text always referred to the element it was being called from.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at square bracket notation.

```
function bake(cookietype,ingredient) {
    var ingredient=document.recipes[ingredient].value;
    document.cookie= cookietype + "=" + ingredient;
}
```

You probably should use a set cookie function. Check out the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global object:

```
var myVars = {};
function bake(cookietype,ingredient) {
    myVars[ingredient] = document.recipes[ingredient].value;
    document.cookie = cookietype + "=" + myVars[ingredient];
}
```

But that's surely not the right way todo this as pointed Ian.

Comment: Not necessarily the right way per se, but it WAS technically the answer to what I asked :) So I learned two new things tonight instead of one :D